# How to sort elements of an array to get a normal distribution results?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
     Example:
            elements := []{
                {Name: "A", Count: 1},
                {Name: "B", Count: 2},
                {Name: "C", Count: 4},
                {Name: "D", Count: 4},
            }

Wants:
1. The smaller the number of elements, the closer to the middle
2. The larger the number of elements, the closer to the edge
3. The same elements are not adjacent to each other as much as possible
4. The distance between the same elements is as equal as possible
5. If there are more elements that cannot meet the above conditions, append to the end of the array
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is for asking questions about code...

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Sort the data by increasing count
- Create two output arrays, each representing two halves of the output, looking from the center of the output outward (so the "left" array will be populated in reverse).
- Grab an occurrence of a name from the sorted data and try each of the two output arrays: if this name is different from the last name added to that array, add the name to it. Give priority to the smallest of the two arrays, but if the name is the same there, then add the name to the other. If also the other does not allow that name, retry with the next object in the sorted input (at index 1)
- Once a name is added to either array, decrease its count in the sorted data list.
- If a counter becomes zero, remove that object from the sorted data list.
- If after repeating the above, an object remains in the data list, then flush those remaining occurrences at the end of the result.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function spread(data) {
    // Clone the data (so not to mutate the original)
    const cloned = data.map(obj => ({...obj}));
    // Sort by count
    cloned.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count);
    // Collect elements in two arrays, each representing half of the output
    const sides = [[], []];
    let i = 0; // can be 0 or 1.
    while (i < cloned.length) {
        const elem = cloned[i];
        if (elem.count == 0) {
            cloned.splice(i, 1); // Remove that depleted element
        } else {
            // Prefered side to populate
            let side = sides[0].length < sides[1].length ? 0 : 1;
            if (sides[side].length > 0 && sides[side].at(-1) == elem.name) {
                // Preferred side won't work. Choose the other side
                side = 1 - side;
            }
            if (sides[side].length > 0 && sides[side].at(-1) == elem.name) {
                // Neither side works, go to the next element and retry
                i++;
            } else {
                // Add one occurrence of the name to the output
                sides[side].push(elem.name);
                elem.count--;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // Reverse the left side and concatenate with right side
    const result = sides[0].reverse().concat(sides[1]);
    // If some name could not be completely depleted according to the rules, so append it
    if (cloned.length > 0) { // Could be 1 (at the most)
        for (let i = 0; i < cloned[0].count; i++) {
            result.push(cloned[0].name);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Example run
const data = [
    {name: "A", count: 1},
    {name: "B", count: 2},
    {name: "C", count: 4},
    {name: "D", count: 4},
];
const result = spread(data);
console.log(...result);
```